# Loop through nested AD groups until all members are found

Tags: powershell

I need help figuring out the logic for looping through Active Directory security groups to find all members of any nested groups using Get-ADGroupMember.  If I use the recursive switch on that cmdlet, it doesn't capture the name of the nested group, just the members.  I need to capture everything.  I feel like this needs to be done using a while or do/while.

This section of code gets me most of the way there.  However, I can't figure out how to prevent it from running the Get-AdGroupMember inside of the while if the objectclass is User.  I'm testing with 4 AD groups called "testgroup1", "testgroup2", "testgroup3" and "testgroup4".  Testgropus 1,2 and 3 each have a single user as a member.  Testgroup2 is a member of Testgroup1.  Testgroup3 is a member of Testgroup2.  Testgroup4 is a member of Testgroup 3 and it also has 4 users as members.

```
$groups = Get-ADGroupMember 'testgroup1'
$allGroups =$null

While($groups){
    $allGroups += $groups.SamAccountName
    $groups = $groups.SamAccountName | Get-ADGroupMember 
}

$allGroups
```

Comment: What is the end goal here, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to go through a list of security groups and find out what objects are members of each group.  If the member is a nested group, then I want to know the members of that group as well.  And so on, until there are no more nested groups.

Comment: Sure, but then why do you need to know the intermediate group names? What is the point of that, and how do you want to incorporate that as part of the output? Are you hoping to produce a report of some sort? CSV, XML?

Comment: I want to gather those names as well to be comprehensive.  Also, yes, a CSV would be the final format.

Comment: So what would the CSV contain? How do you want it to indicate that a group membership is via 1, 2 or more indirect group memberships? Please update your question (preferably with sample desired output)

Comment: I don't care which group that a user object is nested within.  I just want a list of all objects contained within a group, to include the names of the groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We solved this issue by creating a function that gets the members of an AD group and adds only users to an array.  If the object class returns as a group it calls the same function again on that new group and then adds users under it to the same array.  Code is below.

```
function Get-MBusers {
Param (
    $Group,
    $adserver
)

$users=@()    

$members = Get-Adgroup -Identity $Group -Server $adserver -Properties members | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "ForeignSecurityPrincipals"}  | ForEach-Object {Get-ADObject $_ -Server $adserver}
foreach ($member in $members) {
    Write-Debug "$($member.Name)"

    $type = Get-ADObject $member -server $ADServer -Properties samAccountname

    if ($type.ObjectClass -eq 'user') {
        $users += Get-Aduser $type.samaccountname -Server $ADServer
    }

    # If it's a group
    if ($type.ObjectClass -eq 'group') {
        Write-Debug "Breaking out group $($type.Name)"
        $users += Get-MBUsers $member $adserver
    }

}    

return $users
```

}